# How to solve for $x$ with fractional exponents?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am not sure how to solve for $x$ in the problem: $$x+2x^{1/2}+4 = 0$$

I tried using factoring by quadratic form, but that does not work. I don't think the quadratic formula would work either since that would only apply to a quadratic equation. What steps should I take to solve for $x$?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Try substituting $u=\sqrt x$, or just view it as a quadratic in $\sqrt x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the substitution $y = x^{1/2}$ transforms this to a quadratic where you can use your preferred method.